# Django refreshing records at template only after re-running server

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I've just started learning Django and I making my first App. I'm having that weird problem when i adding record to database, it actually adding it there but it won't show them at my page until i reload server by following command

```
python manage.py runserver
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .models import Students

student_data = Students.objects.all()

def homePage(request):
    return render(
        request,
        "pages/homePage.html",
        {"student_data": student_data},
    )


def createStudent(request):
    form = StudentForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StudentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("homePage")
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "pages/addStudent.html", context)


def updateStudent(request, pk):
    student = Students.objects.get(unique_id=pk)
    form = StudentForm(instance=student)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StudentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=student)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("homePage")
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "pages/addStudent.html", context)


def deleteStudent(request, pk):
    student = Students.objects.get(unique_id=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        student.delete()
        return redirect("homePage")
    context = {"object": student}
    return render(request, "pages/delete-template.html", context)


def viewStudent(request, pk):
    student = Students.objects.get(unique_id=pk)
    context = {"student": student}
    return render(request, "pages/view_student.html", context)
```

models.py

```
class Students(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    card_id = models.IntegerField()
    unique_id = models.UUIDField(
         default=uuid.uuid4, 
         unique=True,
         primary_key=True, 
         editable=False)
    student_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default="default_student.jpg")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Students'

    #Methods
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.surname}'
```

addStudent.html

```
{% extends "main.html" %}

{% block addStudent %}
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
{% endblock addStudent %}
```

Here's the image of my home page:
[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPUsq.png)

And this is a form to create a record in database:
[addStudent.html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn9Kd.png)

But after submiting form, django not showing me a record, i've just created.
It just displays nothing.

I need to restart server to see record:

[after re-running server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xObJg.png)

I think that bug appeared after I've started working with static files and added

```
student_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default="default_student.jpg")
```

Has anyone faced that problem before?

Comment: Can you add the view where the created records should be displaying?

Comment: If you want to see added data to the database without refresh you can use ajax

Comment: @IainShelvington added

Comment: @PapisSahine maybe, but it worked just fine before I've started working with static file. I want to figure out what's gone wrong at this point, it must be useful for people in future with the same problem

Comment: Add the view that serves your home page, you likely have a issue with the queryset you are using

Comment: @IainShelvington okay, sorry about that :)

Comment: move the row where you create variable `student_data` into the function where you need it.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko wow, i feel stupid now. Thanks, your answer worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the `student_data` query on every request, currently it's only being executed once and the results of that first query are being reused. You can do this in two ways:

First, you can call `.all()` on the queryset to execute it again if you want to keep `student_data` as a global variable

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Students

student_data = Students.objects.all()


def homePage(request):
    return render(
        request,
        "pages/homePage.html",
        {"student_data": student_data.all()},
    )
```

Second, you can define the queryset on every call to the view to get fresh data

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Students


def homePage(request):
    return render(
        request,
        "pages/homePage.html",
        {"student_data": Students.objects.all()},
    )
```